# How to instantiate a fragment on method instantiateItem?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i'm very new to Android programming, and i'm trying to make the `instantiateItem` on my `SlidingTabsBasicFragment` class, to return the fragment of my `ConversationsFragment`.

In my understanding, my Class `ConversationsFragment` returns a fragment, that would be instantiated. But instead, nothing shows at the second page.

I'm using the `SlidingTabsBasic` sample to make this:

Main Activity onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("Logs", "first");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        //ConversationsFragment fragment = new ConversationsFragment();
        //transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, new ConversationsFragment());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

SlidingTabsBasicFragment:

```
package com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic;

import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;
import com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A basic sample which shows how to use {@link com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout}
 * to display a custom {@link ViewPager} title strip which gives continuous feedback to the user
 * when scrolling.
 */
public class SlidingTabsBasicFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";

    /**
     * A custom {@link ViewPager} title strip which looks much like Tabs present in Android v4.0 and
     * above, but is designed to give continuous feedback to the user when scrolling.
     */
    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;

    /**
     * A {@link ViewPager} which will be used in conjunction with the {@link SlidingTabLayout} above.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    /**
     * Inflates the {@link View} which will be displayed by this {@link Fragment}, from the app's
     * resources.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE (fragment_onviewcreated)
    /**
     * This is called after the {@link #onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)} has finished.
     * Here we can pick out the {@link View}s we need to configure from the content view.
     *
     * We set the {@link ViewPager}'s adapter to be an instance of {@link SamplePagerAdapter}. The
     * {@link SlidingTabLayout} is then given the {@link ViewPager} so that it can populate itself.
     *
     * @param view View created in {@link #onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)}
     */
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)
        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),getActivity()));
        // END_INCLUDE (setup_viewpager)

        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)
        // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
        // it's PagerAdapter set.
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        // END_INCLUDE (setup_slidingtablayout)
    }
    // END_INCLUDE (fragment_onviewcreated)


    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        protected Context mContext;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Item " + (position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if(position==0){
                // return fragment
            }else{
                ConversationsFragment fragment = new ConversationsFragment();
                return fragment;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }


}
```

And this is my ConversationsFragment:

```
public class ConversationsFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * The fragment's ListView/GridView.
 */
private AbsListView mListView;

/**
 * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
 * Views.
 */
private List conversationsListItemList; // at the top of your fragment listW
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
public static ConversationsFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ConversationsFragment fragment = new ConversationsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ConversationsFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    // TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
    conversationsListItemList = new ArrayList();
    conversationsListItemList.add(new ConversationsListItem("Example 1","conversa"));
    conversationsListItemList.add(new ConversationsListItem("Example 2","conversa"));
    conversationsListItemList.add(new ConversationsListItem("Example 3","conversa"));
    mAdapter = new ConversationsListAdapter(getActivity(), conversationsListItemList);
   /* mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS);*/
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversations, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (null != mListener) {
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
    }
}

public void setEmptyText(CharSequence emptyText) {
    View emptyView = mListView.getEmptyView();

    if (emptyView instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) emptyView).setText(emptyText);
    }
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id);
}
```

}

Screenshots:

First Screen:

https://goo.gl/photos/Ze5ThZgevGaALDj47

Second Screen:

https://goo.gl/photos/x7JPnESAtZsBT5DC8

And now this errors appears:

```
06-16 12:32:58.946  12228-12228/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic, PID: 12228
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:417)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:412)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
```

Comment: can you post `SlidingTabsBasic` full class

Comment: Edited the OP with the full class.

Comment: check the answer I posted

Comment: copy same for condition `if()` as if is not returning anything that's why showing nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your code is  returning `View` and `Fragment`

below code worked for me

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    protected Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "" + tabsTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

         if(position==0){
           // return fragment
         }else{
         ConversationsFragment fragment = new ConversationsFragment();
                return fragment;
          }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code, it now extends from `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
But it still shows up blank screens...

Comment: why don't to you use the whole adapter class I provided

Comment: The same error happened, i updated the OP with the error, and the edited file.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh  All, the doc of PagerAdapter (which is base of FragStatePagerADapter and FragPagerAdapter) that instantiateItem() is must be overriden by adapter. I am trying to do that for my FragStatePagerADapter and it has to return Fragment as it holds Fragments. Every version of container that is passed to instantiateItem() has addView() which takes only View type but no generic Object or Fragment type. Could you help me how can I do that ?